# Как правильно сделать редирект с www на без www

Tags: .htaccess, seo

Я сделал редирект данным кодом в файле `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

НО!

Теперь если я перехожу на любую страницу с `www`, то меня редиректит на `http://example.ru/index.php` и кидает `404`.

Как сделать чтобы при переходе на любую страницу с `www` кидало на аналогичную без `www`?

Comment: а зачем четыре w ?

Comment: У Вас почти всё правильно, только во второй строке должно быть `^www\.example\.ru$`. Возможно, есть другие редиректы или в `VirtualHost` `ServerName` или `ServerAlias` неправильно прописаны.

Answer (score 2):

#### Проблема

Поисковые системы считают сайты http://yoursite.ru/ и http://www.yoursite.ru/ абсолютно разными. Отсюда следует, что если часть сайтов будет ссылаться на http://yoursite.ru/, а другая часть на http://www.yoursite.ru/, то ссылочная популярность Вашего сайта делится между разными доменами, что не есть хорошо. С этим надо что-то делать.

#### Решение проблемы

Используя 301 редирект, который автоматически будет переадресовывать всех, кто заходит по ссылке, начинающейся с http://yoursite.ru/ на http://www.yoursite.ru/, Вы сможете дать поисковым системам понять, что эти 2 домена являются как бы одним.Таким образом, ссылочная популярность больше не будет распределяться между двумя доменами, а будет считаться общей, что позволит улучшить позиции сайта в поисковых системах.

#### Установка 301 редиректа домена без WWW на домен с WWW на Apache сервере

1. Прежде всего, убедитесь в том, что на Вашем Apache сервере активен модуль ModRewrite. В основном он активен по умолчанию, но убедиться лишний раз не помешает во избежание проблем в дальнейшем. Если же данный модуль неактивен, то просто свяжитесь со службой поддержки своего хостинг-провайдера и объясните им ситуацию. Проблем при активации данного модуля быть не должно.

   Если же у Вас есть доступ к файлу httpd.conf, то Вы сможете активировать данный модуль собственноручно. Для этого откройте данный файл для редактирования (не забудьте сперва сделать его резервную копию) и раскомментируйте следующую строку:

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```

   После того, как раскомментируете данную строку, сохраните файл и перезагрузите сервер, чтобы продолжить работать дальше.
2. Скачайте на свой компьютер с сервера файл .htaccess
3. Сделайте резервную копию данного файла и сохраните ее, по возможности, в другом месте на компьютере.
4. Откройте оригинальный файл .htaccess для редактирования, например, в блокноте.
5. Теперь добавьте в него следующие строки, но будьте внимательны и не забудьте заменить example.ru на адрес своего сайта

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ru
   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

   И наоборот, кому надо **редирект домена с WWW на домен без WWW:**

   ```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
6. Сохраните изменения в файле и загрузите его на сервер.
7. После этого откройте браузер и в адресной строке введите адрес своего сайта без WWW, например http://example.ru/ и зайдите на сайт. Если Вы все сделали правильно, то в адресной строке браузера автоматически произойдет изменение — адрес сайта с введенного Вами сменится на http://www.example.ru/.
8. Но чтобы на 100% быть уверенным в успешности проделанного я Вам советую зайти [сюда](http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers.asp), ввести адрес сайта без WWW. Данный инструмент покажет Вам, работает ли настроенный Вами 301 редирект или нет. Если Вы все сделали правильно, то должны будете увидеть следующее (особое внимание уделите выделенным жирным участкам кода):

> **№ 1** **Server Response: http://example.ru**

> **HTTP Status Code: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently**

> Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2007 22:49:28 GMT

> Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix) PHP/4.4.1 FrontPage/5.0.2.2510 mod_ssl/2.8.14 OpenSSL/0.9.6b

> **Location: http://www.example.ru/**

> Connection: close

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

> **Redirect Target: http://www.example.ru/**

> **№ 2** **Server Response: http://www.example.ru/**

> **HTTP Status Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

> Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2007 22:49:28 GMT

> Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix) PHP/4.4.1 FrontPage/5.0.2.2510 mod_ssl/2.8.14 OpenSSL/0.9.6b

> Connection: close

> Content-Type: text/html

9. Если у Вас в ключевых (выделенных жирным) местах все сошлось, то все работает!

Если же Вы проделали указанные выше шаги и не добились требуемого результата, то воспользуйтесь резервной копией файла .htaccess – проделайте с ней еще раз все указанные выше шаги, но будьте предельно внимательны. Выверяйте каждый шаг.

Если же и сейчас ничего не получилось, то свяжитесь со службой поддержки своего хостинг-провайдера, объясните им ситуацию и пусть они примут соответствующие меры, нацеленные на решение Вашей проблемы.

[источник](http://www.seoschool.ru/search-engine-optimization-seo/how-to-301-redirect-non-www-to-www-urls.html#microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот метод:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```